# Как я могу использовать аргументы в Faker.password?

Tags: python, selenium, test-automation, pytest

Я пытаюсь добавить в Faker.password аргументы, то есть использовать это как-то так Faker.password(min_length: 10, max_length: 20) что бы управлять длинной получаемого пароля, но получаю ошибку:
faker.password() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_length'
как мне добавить аргументы правильно?

Comment: У `Faker.password` нет параметров `min_length` и `max_length` - есть просто `length` - `Faker.password(length=random.randint(10, 20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идём в `...\Python39\Lib\site-packages\faker\providers\misc\__init__.py`, смотрим:

```python
def password(
    self,
    length: int = 10,
    special_chars: bool = True,
    digits: bool = True,
    upper_case: bool = True,
    lower_case: bool = True,
)
```

Это все возможные аргументы функции. Есть только `length`. Соответственно если есть желание ограничить по минимальному и максимальному значению, то надо использовать `random`:

```python
from faker import Faker
from random import randint

faker = Faker()
for _ in range(0,5):
    print(faker.password(length = randint(10,20)))
```

###### Вывод:

```
$73YA5w!@c&
I_d#_bCl#j+1
IFP3PNbH+H
b*5*nCgrayF)nvREw
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!